# Linq Group By list<Object> sum

Tags: linq, list

```
public class Budget
{
    public string SeasonNo { get; set; }
    public string SeasonName { get; set; }
    public string typeProductCd { get; set; }
    public string typeProductDescription { get; set; }
    public Decimal UsdBudgetRetail { get; set; }
}

List<Budget> list1

List<Budget> list2

List<Budget> ListUngrouped =
    list1.Concat(list2).ToList();

List<Budget> listGrouped = ListUngrouped
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.SeasonNo, x.typeProductCd })
    .Select(group => new { group.Key, UsdBudgetRetail = group.Sum(x => x.UsdActualRetail) })
    .Cast<BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto>()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: what is your question? you might want to clarify what you need if you want help.

Comment: Where is `UsdActualRetail` defined?  Where is `BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto` defined?  How are `list1` and `list2` populated?  How are you casting `List<BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto>` to `List<Budget>`? What is the behavior you got, and what was the expected behavior?  If you got an exception, post the exception message and line number where it occurred.  Can you provide a *complete*, **working** code sample that demonstrates the issue you are having?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Here are some problems with your code as it stands right now that will need to be addressed:

1. `Budget` does not contain a definition of `UsdActualRetail`.
2. `List<BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto>` cannot be casted to `List<Budget>`.
3. The `group` object cannot implicitly be casted to `BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto`.
4. I have already fixed misspellings of `BUDGET`, `concat`, and `toList`.
5. In order to get the grouping to function, you will need to provide a custom implementation for equality comparison for your GroupBy object.

Making a bunch of wild educated guesses about how you want this code to work and what the definitions of the other missing classes might be, here is a (LinqPad-ready) [complete working code sample](http://codepaste.net/5a3oo5) that shows the grouped values and sums, with a working custom equality implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Budget> list1 = new List<Budget>() {
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "1", SeasonName = "Test 1", typeProductCd = "3", UsdActualRetail = 1.01m },
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "1", SeasonName = "Test 2", typeProductCd = "3", UsdActualRetail = 1.01m },
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "1", SeasonName = "Test 3", typeProductCd = "3", UsdActualRetail = 1.01m },
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "1", SeasonName = "Test 4", typeProductCd = "3", UsdActualRetail = 1.01m },
    };

    List<Budget> list2 = new List<Budget>() {
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "2", SeasonName = "Test 5", typeProductCd = "4", UsdActualRetail = 1.02m },
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "2", SeasonName = "Test 6", typeProductCd = "4", UsdActualRetail = 1.02m },
        new Budget { SeasonNo = "2", SeasonName = "Test 7", typeProductCd = "4", UsdActualRetail = 1.02m },
    };

    List<Budget> listUngrouped = list1.Concat(list2).ToList();

    List<BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto> listGrouped = 
        listUngrouped
            .GroupBy(x => new SeasonDto { SeasonNo = x.SeasonNo, typeProductCd = x.typeProductCd })
            .Select(group => new BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto {
                SeasonDto = group.Key,
                UsdBudgetRetail = group.Sum(x => x.UsdActualRetail)
            })
            .Cast<BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto>()
            .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(listGrouped);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class SeasonDto
{
    public string SeasonNo { get; set; }
    public string typeProductCd { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        SeasonDto otherS = other as SeasonDto;
        if (otherS != null)
        {
            return this.SeasonNo.Equals(otherS.SeasonNo) &&
                this.typeProductCd.Equals(otherS.typeProductCd);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return SeasonNo.GetHashCode() + typeProductCd.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto
{
    public SeasonDto SeasonDto { get; set; }
    public decimal UsdBudgetRetail { get; set; }
}

public class Budget
{
        public string SeasonNo { get; set; }
        public string SeasonName { get; set; }
        public string typeProductCd { get; set; }
        public string typeProductDescription { get; set; }
        public Decimal UsdActualRetail { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!  We will be able to help you better if you can improve your question considerably.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , yeah I have somem errors in the attributes but i`ll explain the main idea. I have multiple list of budget,I want to group them first by season than by typeProductCD

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , yeah I have somem errors in the attributes but i`ll explain the main idea. I have multiple list of budget,I want to group them first by season than by typeProductCD and make the sum of USDActual retail of the elements that are  sharing the same UsdActualRetail. i`m expecting a new list as a result so I can manage it to display it in a report, there is no BudgetAndActualLineInfoBySeasonDto it is just Budget(my dto) and UsdBudgetRetail  is  UsdActualRetail